# Angular: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'choice_set' of null, while data displayed correctly

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i hope you're doing well.

I am trying to implement a FormsBuilder in Angular by accessing the data from an API. The data is pushed down to its child-component via @Input().

However the data gets pushed down, are provided and shown successfully, but still I get this Error, when the first attempt from ngOnChangess tries to receive the data.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'choice_set' of null
    at StyleTypeQuestionComponent.setFormValues (style-type-question.component.ts:34)
    at StyleTypeQuestionComponent.ngOnChanges (style-type-question.component.ts:26)
    at StyleTypeQuestionComponent.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.js:1471)
    at callHook (core.js:2490)
    at callHooks (core.js:2457)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2408)
    at refreshView (core.js:9207)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:10312)
    at refreshView (core.js:9216)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10358)
```

The data is provided through an data-service and are subscribed through an async pipe from its parent-component and as mentioned above pushed down via property binding.

I tried to use the ? operator in my template and tried to set an Timeout on the childcomponent. Also i tried to initialize the data via default values. Still thats making no sense for me right know, because the data is already available through his parent component and getting checked via an *ngIf directive.

I hope i could provided as much as information as needed.

I guess there is an initializing problem in the first seconds of ngChanges.

**Parent-Component**

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Question } from '../shared/models/question';
import { QuestionStoreService } from '../shared/question-store.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'pc-style-type-detection',
  templateUrl: './style-type-detection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./style-type-detection.component.css'],
})
export class StyleTypeDetectionComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  question$: Observable<Question>;
  @Input() question_Input: Question;

  question_index: number = 1;

  constructor(private qs: QuestionStoreService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.question$ = this.qs.getSingle(1);
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {}

  updateBook(question: Question): void {
    console.log(question);
  }
}
```

**Parent-Template**

```
<pc-style-type-question
  *ngIf="question$"
  (submitQuestion)="updateBook($event)"
  [question]="question$ | async"
></pc-style-type-question>
```

**Child-Component**

```
import {
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  OnInit,
  Output,
} from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Choice, Question } from '../shared/models/question';

@Component({
  selector: 'pc-style-type-question',
  templateUrl: './style-type-question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./style-type-question.component.css']
})
export class StyleTypeQuestionComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  questionForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() question: Question;
  @Output() submitQuestion = new EventEmitter<Question>();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.initForm();
    this.setFormValues(this.question);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
  }

  private setFormValues = (question: Question) => {
    this.questionForm.patchValue(question.choice_set);

    this.questionForm.setControl(
      'choice_set',
      this.buildChoiceSetArray(question.choice_set)
    );
  };

  initForm = () => {
    if (this.questionForm) {
      return;
    }

    this.questionForm = this.fb.group({
      choice_set: this.buildChoiceSetArray([
        {
          choice_text: '',
          choice_value: false,
        },
      ]),
    });
  };

  get choiceSet(): FormArray {
    return this.questionForm.get('choice_set') as FormArray;
  }

  private buildChoiceSetArray = (values: Choice[]): FormArray => {
    if (values) {
      return this.fb.array(
        values.map((choice) => {
          return this.fb.control(choice.choice_value);
        })
      );
    }
    return this.fb.array(
      this.question.choice_set.map((choices) =>
        this.fb.control(choices.choice_value)
      )
    );
  };

  submitForm() {}
}
```

**Child-Template**

```
<form class="ui form" [formGroup]="questionForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  <div
    formArrayName="choice_set"
    *ngFor="let choiceset of choiceSet?.controls; index as i"
  >
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="choiceset" />
      <label>
        {{ question.choice_set[i].choice_text }}
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thank you in advance and wish you a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `ngOnChanges` the right way, its going to be triggered everytime your input change no matter what the value is which means you need to check if that value is what you expect it to be with `SimpleChanges`.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes.question.currentValue) {
        this.initForm();
        this.setFormValues(this.question);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Also i had to add additional ? parameter in the template file of the child component like  `{{ question?.choice_set[i].choice_text }}` to receive the its value